# CMake "make install" or including a library in windows

Tags: c++, windows, github, cmake, cmake-gui

I'm trying to create an Open Source C++ project. I want it to be as easy to build as possible, but at the same time cross platform.
I don't need gui or heavy libraries like boost or Qt, so I've settled on using GitHub, CMake, and LibSourcey.
My problem is, I can't find a way to make my project easy to build in windows, which is my development environment.
How can I "make install" a library in Windows for use in my project? Do I even have to install it in windows?
Is it possible to download, build, and link it automatically?

On windows, besides an installer, I also want to make a portable version, so don't want any hard coded library paths.

I assume, on some platforms, like Linux, libraries are built separably and packaged up by maintainers. So I shouldn't just bundle up my own copies.

So, my question is:
How can I set up a project that is cross platform and easy to build, and what are the best practices?

Comment: I am not sure if you are talking about finding a solution for your development process or for making releases or both? [msys2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/) can be used under windows to manage your required packages.

Comment: I hit the same problem lately, msys2 look great, but I prefer using native toolchain for windows developement.

Comment: I looked into msys, but I want it to be native. With msys it's even harder to compile for x64 and with proper unicode support.

Comment: MSYS2 provides native and POSIX toolchains.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot The question is too broad, more details should be given.

Comment: Should I open another question for my similar problem then?

Comment: This question is indeed rather broad, in that it asks both about the dev side as well as the deployment side. @GuillaumeRacicot - given your bounty description, I'd say another question with your details (export, etc.) would really make more sense.

Comment: A make install on Windows is not intrinsically different from a make install on Linux. It creates a "deployment" version of a library, i.e. copying over the binaries, perhaps headers, etc. but leaves behind all the "build" cruft not necessary after deployment. If you generate a Visual Studio project it will also generate an INSTALL project which you can use as a target for "deployment". The equivalent of 'make install' is then to build the INSTALL target (or call 'msbuild INSTALL.vcxproj')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `git submodule` in your git repo with path for example
`contrib/LibSourcery` and url to github repo of `LibSourcery`, because of `LibSourcery` uses `cmake` you just
need add such line into your `CMakeLists.txt`: `add_subdirectory(contrib/LibSourcery)`

So person who want to use your code, just do `git clone --recursive url`
to get all of your code and dependencies, after that it run `cmake -G`, to create project for `IDE` of his choice (including MSVC++ of course),
open project in `IDE` and press build button, that's all.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or LibSourcery doesn't support this type of inclusion.
I did include it in contrib folder as submodule, but I'm still not sure if that's the right way to include a library on Unix platforms. Would it link to the installed library if it's available? How do it add includes?

Comment: @denisps cmake also support external projects in such way https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html

Comment: This answer seems to be the closest. Unfortunately, LibSourcery seems to be broken and potentially abandoned.
I would appreciate if you elaborate on how to take into account the case when I'm linking to the library that is already installed on, for instance, Linux.

Comment: @denisps In case of already installed library there is no universal answer. In the most simple case, when you work on `Linux`, headers of library in `/usr/include` and compiled code in `/usr/lib` you need just add `-llibname` into `target_link_libraries`. If something more complex, for example you want not only `Linux` support, or library install files in sub-directories of `/usr/lib` `/usr/include`, you need to use `find_package`, `find_library` and other stuff, and how you should handle this situtation depend on library, and fact that some one from cmake community work with it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use [babun](http://babun.github.io). It's a wrapper for cygwin and it works perfectly for everything I need, even compiling with cmake.

Alternatively, you could use [premake](https://premake.github.io/), which uses lua as a config system and works fine on windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is no elegant cross-platform way, since the idea of "make install" doesn't exist on Windows, therefore the use of cmake install is undefined there. For something which is supposed to help cross-platform, I feel this is a deficiency w cmake.

My solution is to write a custom _INSTALL which takes the same args as cmake install and then on Linux it just calls install, and on Windows it does an add_command which does a post-build copy to the install paths, which accomplishes the same thing. Basically, _INSTALL behaves the way you expect a cross-platform install command to behave. Can share my _INSTALL func if there is interest.

_INSTALL is placed nto a Helper.cmake, and included in all my CMakeList.txt for my projects, so all I need to do is call it and the generated lib/inc files magically appear for both win and linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/index.html), an open source package manager for c and c++. It allows to easily download and compile libraries and then use find_package from within CMake like you would on linux. It's very easy to use. It even provides hints as to how to alter your cmake file to use the libraries.

I started by installing packages with the command line, and then wondered why they wouldn't show up in visual studio. But I realized that it would download 32 bit libraries by default. Use `.\vcpkg install <libname>:x64-windows` if you need the 64 bit libraries.

After running the integrate command, you will need to delete any cmake caches to have MSVS use the new toolchain.